# Yii2 logout timeout

Tags: yii2, логирование, timeout

Как мне реализовать автоматический выход пользователя через `Yii::$app->user->logout`чтоб он выполнялся через 15 минут в случаи если пользователь не активен,

Answer (score 1):

Заходим в **config/web.php** и находим массив с ключом **user**.

Добавляем значение `'authTimeout' => 120`

В конечном итоге должно примерно выглядеть так:

```
'user' => [
     'identityClass' => 'app\components\UserIdentity',
     'enableAutoLogin' => true,
     'loginUrl' => ['login/index'],
     'authTimeout' => '120', //секунды
],
```

Comment: `enableAutoLogin` и  `loginUrl` могут выглядеть по-другому и особой роли в процессе не играют :)

Comment: Я написал, что примерно должно выглядеть так. Так наглядно видно, куда надо прописать параметр authTimeout. А он и является основным ответом на данный вопрос